# TreeNode - PrimeNG - Typescript: How to Remove a node from tree?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Can someone tell me how to remove a specific node from my tree ?

Example:
 root node(this.documentsTree[0])
 children(this.documentsTree[0].children[0], this.documentsTree[0].children[1]). The first child also have a child(this.documentsTree[0].children[0].children[0]) <= This is just a small example. I'm working with Angular and I'm using Tree from **PrimeNG**. Below you can see some part of my code. **Thanks!**:

```
import {TreeModule} from 'primeng/tree';
import {TreeNode} from 'primeng/api';
export class DocumentsComponent implements OnInit {

documentsTree: TreeNode[] = [];


private createNode(category: CategoryModel) {
 let node = {
   data: category,
   label: category.name,
   expandedIcon: "fa-folder-open",
   collapsedIcon: "fa-folder",
   expanded: category.id == 1,
   children: [],
   leaf: false
 };
 category.children.forEach(x => node.children.push(this.createNode(x)));
 return node;
 }

private loadCategoryTree() {

  this.documentsTree = [];
  var node = this.createNode(this.documentCategoryDTO);
  this.documentsTree = [node];
  this.documentsTreeAux = this.documentsTree;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is the method I used for deleting from a primeng tree adapted to your example, supposing your node data has a unique identifier (ex. ID).

```
deleteNode(topNode: TreeNode, selectedNode: TreeNode) {
        if (topNode.children != null) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < topNode.children.length; i++) {
                if (topNode.children[i].data.id == selectedNode.data.id) {
                    topNode.children.splice(i, 1);   
                    return;
                }
                else this.deleteNode(topNode.children[i], selectedNode);
            }
        }
        else return;
    }
```

And you can use it like this:`this.deleteNode(this.documentsTree[0], selectedNode);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works, but it doesn't refresh UI. When is collapse and expand then it works.